# How to download content that is downloaded by button click

Tags: python, download

I am trying to download a page from internet using

```
def getContent(self)
    intermediate = urllib2.urlopen(self.link)
    self.content = intermediate.read()
```

The problem that I am having is that the stuff that gets downloaded is not complete. More than half of the html page is truncated. [This](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Work%2C%20Job%2C%20Christmas&cmpt=q) is a sample page. I am trying to get the content that describes the graph, and after parse it. Trying something like :

```
self.content = intermediate.read()
self.content += intermediate.read()
```

doesn't help either because every subsequent call to `intermediate.read()` after the 1st one do not produce any output.

How can I fix my python code to get the whole content of the page?

If this is not possible for some odd reasons, how can I get the content that gets downloaded when the button `Download as CSV` is pressed on the page:

[image: Download]

You can see this image in the link posted above as well.